# Textbook question about inner product and work.

Tags: vectors

I have this questions from my textbook:

[image]

I don't understand this line:

$b = [-1, tan {25}] = [-1, 0.46631], thus |b| = 1.10338$

Where does the length b come from? How did 1.10338 come about? Why are we using tan 25? I don't understand the u line either.

Answer (score 2):

$b$ is a vector in the direction of the rope, it represents nothing in particular, and this vector's components are $(-1,\tan 25)$ (note that any vector in the direction of the rope must be a multiple of this one, so they took this one for simplicity)

And so the length of $b$ is $|b|=\sqrt{(-1)^2+ (\tan 25)^2}$

And how he got the components of $b$, in the right triangle (where the hypotenuse is the inclined plane that the car is on) we may suppose that the horizantal side of this triangle has a length of $1$ and $\tan 25=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}= \frac{\text{y-component of} \quad b}{1}$

[image]

To find the components of the vector of the direction of the rope you simply project it on the x-axis and y-axis

If the x-component was $-1$ then we calculate the y-component as above to find that it is $\tan 25$.

So $b=(-1,\tan 25)$

Note that during calculation of the y-component we used $1$ and not $-1$ because we are using the length which is always positive (and the $-$ actually is just for direction because it is opposite to the direction of the x axis)

Comment: Why is B, the vector in the direction of the rope, have the x component of -1 and the y component of tan 25? Why is the y component tan 25?

Comment: Where does the unit vector come from in the next line?

Comment: For any $\vec v$, to get the unit vector $\vec w$ that has the same direction as $\vec v$  you simply divide by the norm (i.e. magnitude) of the vector $\vec v$. Notice that $||\vec w||=\left\Vert \frac{\vec v}{||\vec v||}\right\Vert= \frac{||\vec v||}{||\vec v||}=1$ and thus $\vec w$ is a unit vector and it clearly is in the direction of $\vec v$

Comment: I edited the answer. If there is still anything you don't understand please ask.

Comment: is the unit vector here the displacement? Is that what is going on? They are determining the force of -p by finding p (the displacement represented by u) and a and doing $a \cdot p$

Comment: The force $a$ has a part $c$ that is perpendicular to the motion of the car so it doesn't effect it, we are just intrested in the part $p$ of $a$ that is along the motion of the car. So we find the projection of $a$ along the direction of the motion of the car $|a|\cos(\gamma)$. So the rope must pull the car by a force of magnitude $|a|\cos(\gamma)$, but in what direction? In the direction of $u$ (same direction as $-p$). ($u$ must be a unit vector so that it doesn't affect the magnitude).